# How to increment the int variable inside the print statement in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing, increment

I want to increment the variable inside the print statement, so it would not take 2 lines of code.

I have the following code:

```
yearCount += 1    
print("Year ",yearCount,":",sep = "")
```

How can I do something like:

```
print("Year",yearCount+=1,":",sep = "")
```

Comment: Less lines aren't automatically better. By shoving side effects into a `print`, you're obscuring the control flow and making your code *harder* to read.

Comment: It is good to have this page as it just tells people that come here to just not do it as it is harder to read.

Answer (score 1):

For printing *only*, you can use f-strings, available in v3.6+:

```
print(f'Year {yearCount+1}:')
```

If you *also* need to increment the variable itself, I would stick with the two-liner; it's best to be clear and differentiate between calculations and printed output.

---

A not recommended answer to your question would be:

```
yearCount += 1; print(f'Year {yearCount}:')
```

Comment: this does not increment the variable. it just prints the value + 1

Comment: @SonicSoul, Yes, that's right. The answer is, as I've explained, don't increment variables in a print statement.

Answer (score -1):

Use format to format the string for printing and not actually incrementing the value

```
print("Year {}".format(yearCount+1))
```

Answer (score -1):

You can go through official doc for `print` function [Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html).

```
 a = 2
 print("Sum is :", a+3)
```

output is :

```
 Sum is :5
```

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible to initialize variable(s) within `print()`. The best thing that you could do is call a function via f-string. Use that called function to increment the variable that you want.

```
yearCount = 2018
def yearInc():
  global yearCount
  yearCount+=1
  return yearCount

print(f"Year {yearInc()}")
print(f'Year {yearCount}')
```

The output is:

```
Year 2019
Year 2019
```

This solution may be wasteful if you just to call this function once.